# Handsontable edit data on row change

Tags: handsontable

I am using NGHandontable datagrid. I am facing one problem that it I am not finding its row Change event. I need it because If I save  data on afterchange event in database table, then server will get hit on every cell change which can cause performance problem.

So I want to hit the server on row change event so that it will get hit after all the changes that are done for a row.

Please help me with some suggestion or work around of this problem.

Comment: let me know if any clarifications needed on question.

Comment: Thanks Niladri Sekhar Basu